# Smooth transition of Images when swiping

Tags: android, image

I have an array of urls, which I load in an Image View.

I scroll through the pics using swipe gestures. That works.

However, what doesnt happen , is a smooth transition of the pics. I.e, while I swipe, I cant the current pic being moved out, and the next pic coming in, as it does in any gallery view.

I'm sure there are lot of threads in this topic, just dint know what to search for.

Any help/redirection would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about implementing [Swipe Views](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/swipe-views.html), if so, look at implementing a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) (also see this [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html)).

Comment: Hey AdamK,Thanks for the reply. Yes, this seems to be what I'm looking for. However, I did run into some pages that described the same thing as animation - i.e, left to right animation and the pother way around clubbed with gestures while flipping though images. Are they different approaches to the same issue? Any one method preferred ?

Comment: The ViewPager method is preferred and much easier to implement - it essentially wraps up the gestures + animation code into an easy-to-use class for you. It was only introduced more recently which is probably why you see tutorials/pages on building this functionality yourself still.

Comment: Hey Adam, I'm having difficulty spotting a decent example demonstrating the use of basic ViewPager. A push towards a right url by any chance?

Comment: The blog post I linked to above has a basic example. For a more complex example look at this Android Training class: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html